# Why do I get 127.0.0.1?

Tags: c#, localhost, ip-address

Why do I get `127.0.0.1`? How can I get IP address?

```
localIP = "?";

try {   
    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    
    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList) {
        if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork") {
            localIP = ip.ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) { 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.toString());
}
```

Comment: Try posting your code using the code tags in the editor so it is formatted properly then it will be easier for us to help... A bit more info on what you are trying to achieve would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Because it the default loopback address. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). Unless you have an LAN adapter configured with any other IP address, this is the default.